# Public class <Generic type> implements Comparable

Tags: java, comparable, compareto, implements

I have an Public class Account that i want to implement with comparable and my question is the following:

**how can I make that the account with the lowest balance is the "smallest" in my comparison?**.

```
public class Account implements Comparable<Account>{
  private double balance;
  private String acctNum;

  public Account(String number, double initBal){
      balance = initBal;
      acctNum = number;
  }
  public double getBalance(){
      return balance;
  }
  .....


 public int compareTo(Account other) {
         ????????
  }
```

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) for that method?

Comment: [This method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method must return:

- a negative integer if this is less than other,
- zero if this is equal to other
- a positive integer if this or greater than other

Just doing `return this.balance - other.balance` can give invalid results if values are near `Double.MAX_VALUE` or `Double.MIN_VALUE`, so you should use [`Double.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)):

```
public int compareTo(Account other) {
    return Double.compare(this.balance, other.balance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement is to use a `Double` as the type for `balance` and simply call `compareTo` method:

```
return balance.compareTo(other);
```

I'm not saying that this is the best but it is good enough for a start.

Note that handling `null`s is up to you to implement.

Comment: This wouldn't compile. That's not how autoboxing works.

Comment: @AndyTurner It says use `Double`. It wouldn't compile because `other` is not a `Double`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington it wouldn't compile because `balance` is a `double`, not a `Double`, and you can't invoke `compareTo` on a `double`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Read the full answer again... It's a strange answer, but that is not the problem.

Comment: @PaulBoddington [you can't invoke `compareTo` on a `double`](http://ideone.com/HUyBK9).

Comment: That's why I said he should use `Double`. The other answer is just as good or even better.

Comment: @AndyTurner which part of "The simplest way to implement is to use a `Double` as the type for balance " you don't understand?

Comment: The bit where I misread it and you didn't simply use `Double.compareTo` :)